# How to html decode values in databound asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Is it possible to html decode the text value displayed in an asp.net dropdown control using the datatextformatstring property?

Comment: Do you want to decode it server side or client side ? Are you using WebForms or MVC ?

Comment: Using webforms. Is there some kind of special format string that will render htmldecoded text?

Comment: You do not need to encode the text for it to be displayed properly. If however, your text is already encoded, use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) in the ItemDataBound event of your dropdown to manually decode each item after it has been bound.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid wiring up an event handler to do that. I was hoping there was a format string I could use in the datatextformatstring property of the dropdown that would do it.